# c++ / application with multiple separate windows

Tags: c++, winapi

So i have this code that creates two windows:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = StaticWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("Move Engine");
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    m_hWnd = CreateWindow("Move Engine", "Move Engine", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, usWidth, usHeight, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, this);

    // Create the settings window
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("Settings");
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    s_hWnd = CreateWindow("Settings", "Settings", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 20, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, this);

ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(s_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

The problem is, application terminates each time i close one of the windows. What i need is two separate windows; main application window and the one that gives access to various settings of the application - therefore closing the settings window should not affect the main window. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

---

P.S. My WinMain function is modified like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE a_hInstance, HINSTANCE a_hPrevInstance, LPTSTR a_lpCmdLine, int a_iCmdShow)
{
    int iReturnCode;

    // Initialise the engine.
    if (!MyEngine.InitInstance(a_hInstance, a_lpCmdLine, a_iCmdShow)) return 0;

    // Begin the gameplay process and return when the application due to exit
    iReturnCode = MyEngine.StartEngine();

    // Return the correct exit code.
    return iReturnCode;
}
```

and StaticWndProc looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CMoveEngine::StaticWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // If this is a create message, trap the 'this' pointer passed in and store it within the window.
    if (Message == WM_CREATE) SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)((CREATESTRUCT FAR *)lParam)->lpCreateParams);

    // Obtain the correct destination for this message
    CMoveEngine *Destination = (CMoveEngine*)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA);

    // If the hWnd has a related class, pass it through
    if (Destination) return Destination->DisplayWndProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);

    // No destination found, defer to system...
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Message loop:

```
int CMoveEngine::StartEngine()
{
    MSG msg;
// Start main loop
while (true) 
{
    // Did we recieve a message, or are we idling?
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    } 
    else 
    {

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your StaticWndProc do in response to WM_CLOSE etc? What does your message loop look like?

Comment: @Tom Whittock it posts a quit message: `PostQuitMessage(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You register both window classes with the same `lpfnWndProc`. Thus, all the messages (including mouse clicks and keyboard presses) will be directed to the same function, `StaticWndProc`.

Thus, when this function receives the [`WM_CLOSE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617.aspx), it will respond by destroying the window, which stops the message pump and terminates the program. Since both windows have the same message handler function, they will both respond in the same way.

The solution is to define two different `WndProc` methods, one for each of your windows, or special-case the handling of the `WM_CLOSE` message, only calling `DefWindowProc` for the window that you want to allow to close the entire application.

Comment: Your recollection was precisely correct. I took the liberty of expanding your answer just a tiny bit, and removed the indication of self-doubt. Hope you don't mind! :-)

Comment: Can you please show me how i should implement the second `StaticWndProc` function in the above context?

Answer (score 2):

Make your `StaticWndProc` handle either `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_DESTROY`: In that case it should decrement an openedWindows-counter. If that counter reaches zero call `PostQuitMessage`.

Comment: I've just read a little bit about this case, but its still unclear to me - is there any way to make each window receive its own set of messages?

Comment: @Abdulali: Yes, register a different `WndProc` function for each of the windows when you create them with `RegisterClass`.